# Is it necessary to add logging and audit in every class diagram

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram, audit-logging

I going to start a new application for that am designing class diagrams...
In my application I am planning to implement log4j for logging and audit4j for audit.
Now i am having a doubt, Is it necessary to add logging and audit functionality in UML(Class Diagram) because each class using both of them and it is default understandable. If I add them my UML looks so clumsy and unclear..

Is it advisable to remove logging and audit from UML. Will it cause any drawbacks while construction...

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Reason for down vote will help me to ask questions in a better way...

Answer (score 1):

Class diagrams and other UML diagrams serve the purpose of clarifying the interdependencies and interactions between the modules and classes.  As you mentioned, adding unnecessary details which are cross cutting across modules/classes ***will clutter your diagrams and will not add any value.***

As a developer looking at class diagrams, I would not want to see the loggers/audits.  You can add the details about these cross cutting functionalities in your other specs/documentations.

Comment: Hehe. Cross-posting almost the same answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

UML is not about diagrams, it's about models. Your diagrams help humans to understand the model. You create more than one diagram to highlight a certain aspect. If you try to document a 3-dimensional sculpture with 2-dimensional photos you also need to make more than one photo. Some of those photos will have duplicate (redundant) information. You can crop them if needed. But sometimes you need that for the context.

To sum up: make as many diagrams a needed. Focus in some. Make a more global picture in others. It's an art of its own to get good pictures.